# Swap Date around on a Natural Programming language variable?

Tags: mainframe

I am trying to find a way to flip a date around in the natural programming language.

What I have is a #DOB which is equal to 19700830  yyyymmdd and I need it to be mmddyyyy. Is there an easy way to do this in Natural?

**Question: How can I flip the date around to my specific format the easiest and most
           efficient way in Natural?**

Code:

```
    RESET #NAME(A21/25) 
          #ROLE(A7/25) 
          #DOB(A10) 
          #I(P3)    
          #ADC(A1/25) 
          #SSN(A9)
```

I have tried using the FOR loop to get my results, but it is bulky and won't compile as of yet.. It is bulky at best.

```
    FOR INDEX(P3) FROM 1 TO 8
       IF INDEX >= 1 AND INDEX <= 4
          #YYYY = #DOB(INDEX) 

       IF INDEX >= 5 AND INDEX <= 6
          #MM = #DOB(INDEX) 

       IF INDEX >= 7 AND INDEX <= 7
          #DD = #DOB(INDEX) 
    LOOP
```

This is what I would like to do but I am not completely certain that it will work. I think there is a better way but I do not have any real great books on the language and it is something that I do not do all that often. Once or twice a year so it is new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is two redefine your variable and them just move and use the pieces of the redefine.

```
    DEFINE   #DOB(A10) 
    REDEFINE #DOB(#Y(A4) #M(A2) #D(A2))
```

Then you can just use the piece and move them around the way that you want.

```
    WRITE WORK FILE 2 #M ',' #D ',' #Y
```